# NULL in a string can't copy contents after NUL

Tags: c#, string, nul

I have a slight issue when I am getting data back from an external device in bytes and then converting it to a string. I am communicating to this device via a TcpClient.

I receive a message from this external device and format it as a string. The problem I am getting is, the message I get back contains a **"NUL"**. When I try to read its contents the string terminates after it comes across NUL in the string. For example:

```
hello world NUL blah blah blah
```

When I add a watcher I don't see `blah blah blah` in the variable or if I do a normal copy and paste in windows of the whole line (above) it will only copy up to hello world. Its like it is cut off or terminated off the string. Never come across this before.

Perhaps it is the way I reading the byte[] data?

*EDIT*

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzr1rvmxiyh4yt3/stack.log

Link to the file (hopefully this is allowed) and the code to read this is:

```
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\stack.log"))
        {
            str.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

See the StringBuilder contents doesn't know anything after the NUL character.

Thanks in advance, Onam.

Hope there is enough detail if not I shall add more if required.

Comment: Probably because you are handling it like a null-terminated string.

Comment: Attached a link to the file that contains the NUL and code to read it. You can visualize what is happening essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search and replace \0 with an empty string or space.

Comment: Waiting on SO to allow me to accept this as answer. Didn't realise it was this simple!